# Clarification on Toyota Coralla Winter Tires

Tags: toyota, tires, wheels, corolla

I placed an online order today for 4 wheels and 4 winter tyres

- Wheels - 15 in steel Wheel - X 45921

  - Tire  - 205/55 R16

Clarification -  Will R16 tyres fit on 15 in Steel wheels ?
                        OR I will to buy a 16 inc Steel wheels only

Please do let me know -  I will immediately have to amend my order

Comment: 15” tires fit a 15” inch wheel, 16” inch tires fit a 16” inch wheel. Suggest you cancel the order and see a tire shop.

Answer (score 1):

No 16 in tires won't fit on 15 in wheels. Change either tires or wheels.
In cold conditions (snow) it's better to go with smaller size wheels, I suggest you to keep the 15 wheels and get 15 tires.

Comment: It is not a smaller diameter that helps in snow, but a smaller width : to help “cut through” the snow...

Comment: @SolarMike I agree with you, generally 15" wheels are with smaller width than 16" wheels. Also the smaller the wheel is the less likely is it to bend in pot hole. Not to mention rough ride of bigger wheels.

Comment: Rough ride? Difference between 15 & 16 hardly, 16 to 19 I agree